# Query for PSQL determine no.of patients in system current time

Tags: psql, psqlodbc

```
select room_id,count (distinct(patient_id)) as patient_id 
from patient_flow where time='CURRENT_TIME';
```

I need the number of patients ids with corresponding room_ids at the current time.

```
 id | patient_id  | room_id |        time
----+-------------+---------+---------------------
  1 | 00035-67351 |       1 | 2015-06-09 10:11:20
  1 | 00035-67351 |       2 | 2015-06-09 10:31:20
  1 | 00035-67351 |       1 | 2015-06-09 10:12:20
  1 | 00035-67351 |       1 | 2015-06-09 10:12:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       1 | 2015-06-09 10:15:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       1 | 2015-06-09 10:30:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       2 | 2015-06-09 10:32:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       2 | 2015-06-09 10:36:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       2 | 2015-06-09 10:38:40
  1 | 00035-67351 |       2 | 2015-06-09 10:50:40
```

I wrote the query above, but it does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `GROUP BY` when using with aggregate function `COUNT()`. The below query will work:

```
SELECT room_id, COUNT (DISTINCT(patient_id)) AS patient_id 
FROM patient_flow 
WHERE time = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY room_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I got ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported.

Comment: Can you try, `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIME`

Comment: Can you try without `'` around the `CURRENT_DATE`?  Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select current_time, room_id, count (distinct(patient_id)) as patient_id from patient_flow  group by room_id;
```

I got result while executing above query..